# this is giving me a parse error

Tags: php, pdo

the code giving me the parse error

```
$sql = INSERT INTO 'tdrilslt_ramen'.'awnsers' ('name', 'choices');
```

the whole code

```
<?php

include 'database.php';

try{
$name = $_POST['name']; 

$sql = INSERT INTO 'tdrilslt_ramen'.'awnsers' ('name', 'choices');
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(
    ':name '=> $name,
    ':choices ' => $choices));

}catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
exit;
}


 ?>
```

Comment: Did you look at the first pages of the php manual? How string variables are defined and initialized. `$sql = "INSERT INTO tdrilslt_ramen.awnsers (name, choices)";`

Comment: `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` <= you need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong identifiers for your db/table.

It should be backticks (note the quotes you are presently using)

Plus, you are using PDO and using quotes for your column names `('name', 'choices')` that is incorrect. They should be `:` placeholders:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tdrilslt_ramen`.`awnsers` (:name, :choices)";
```

Comment: and `('name', 'choices')` to `(:name, :choices)`

Comment: This one's a regular can 'o worms.... `awnsers` who knows if that's spelled the same way in DB. Glad I didn't touch this one.

Comment: I had originally changed to the right spelling and then thought better of it. Maybe they copied and pasted.

Comment: We'll wait till OP comes back and says "Oh thank you, oh thank you!" ;)

Comment: One thing though, OP shows only `$name = $_POST['name'];` and nothing for `$choices`, *scary.*

Comment: Plus who knows what's inside `database.php`... `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? OP didn't tag as PDO. Nope, this one's all yours Jay ;) good luck buddy.

Comment: Don't worry guys he at least tries to have exception handling in this piece of art so no worries. If only that `catch` statement could work...

Comment: @Kypros The present Try/catch OP is using isn't enough and next to useless really. `catch(PDOException $e) { print $e->getMessage(); }` is better and should be using `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` after PDO connection. That usually brings the bugs out from underneath the ground ;)

Comment: I know and the way it is now is a syntax error without at least `catch(Exception $e) {}`

Comment: Some days I think that SO just needs the '*sigh*' button.

Comment: Can't do that Jay, would be nice, but then FB would probably start complaining that we're taking away all their users. Now to pull out my favorite cat photos; not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i did misspelled it in the database. i decided just to leave it. and in the database.php i used pdo but i didn't realize that i needed to add that tag in the question.

Comment: @tearisha It's usually best. You would be surprised as to how many questions I've seen in the past, where the OP was actually using another API to connect with and not associated with the query type. You don't have to add it, but making a note about the API being used is always a given :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes to enclose the string

```
$sql = "Select ........ ";
```